# Cannot return a public list as the return type of a method

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a public class like below that also has another nested public class inside it

```
public class OuterClass
{ 
   // other stuff
   public class InnerClass
   {
      // some public get set properties 
   }

   public List<InnerClass>  InnerClasses;
}
```

Then in my repository I have a method like this:

```
public InnerClass.InnerClasses MyGetMethod()
{
   // go get stuff from DB
}
```

**BUT** it doesn't allow me do that! I can't use `InnerClass.InnerClasses` as the type of that method.  Why?

Comment: InnerClass.InnerClasses is not a type, rather a public variable

Comment: Do you want a custom type like `public class InnerClasses : List<OuterClass.InnerClass> { }`?

Comment: That's simply a typo... the return type you mean is `List<OuterClass.InnerClass>`. The `InnerClasses` is the _field_ in `OuterClass` of type `List<OuterClass.InnerClass>`

Comment: @Bohn Whatever be the reason it was written in that tough fashion but if you want code to work as you posted in your question you need to move `public List<InnerClass> InnerClasses` inside `InnerClass` class as you are trying to access `InnerClass.InnerClasses`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InnerClasses` is field in your class, so it can't be used like a type.

You probably want `OuterClass.InnerClass` as your output type or `List<OuterClass.InnerClass>`:

```
//public OuterClass.InnerClass MyGetMethod()
public List<OuterClass.InnerClass> MyGetMethod()
{
    // go get stuff from DB
}
```

Comment: oh ok ... I thought whatever Public scope, I can put as return type of a method. Ok makes sense. Thansks

Comment: @Bohn you can put **types** as a return **type**, not properties, fields or methods